# Eacces permission denied ghost digitalocean

Tags: digital-ocean, ghost-blog

I created a droplet with ghost one application from digital ocean and I need to configure the domain using the ghost setup command but when it is in root it does not allow it, so I created a user but it complains the error below:

```
Eacces permission denied open var/www/ghost/config.production.json
```